# Using the String replacer node in Knime to extract a number from a string with Regex

Tags: java, regex, string, knime

I'm trying to use the string replacer node in Knime with a regex expression to standardize a field in a database. I need to extract a number from a string, and then replace the entire string with that number. For example,

String: `The Yearly order limit = 5,000`

The result would be: `5,000`

String: `monthly order limit is 5`

Result: `5`

But, I also need to know whether it is a monthly, quarterly, or yearly limit as well. Some of the variations I've tried are: `.\*yearly.*([0-9,]+)` and variations there of. Simply using `([0-9,]+)` gets the number for me, but does not identify anything else. Including anything outside the parentheses will match the whole string overall, but referring to capture group 1 gives me a 0 every time, regardless of what the number is. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check how to create How to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so that you can get a much better response to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (escaped to be used in Java string literals):

```
(?i)[\\w ]*(yearly|monthly|quarterly)[\\w ]*(?:is|=) *([\\d,]+)
```

Now the yearly/monthly/quarterly is in `group(1)`, and the number in `group(2)`.

Full scala example (try online with Scastie, if you want; To convert to Java, add `System.out` and semicolons etc.):

```
val examples = List(
  "The Yearly order limit = 5,000",
  "monthly order limit is 5"
)

import java.util.regex.Pattern
import java.util.regex.Matcher

val p = Pattern.compile("(?i)[\\w ]*(yearly|monthly|quarterly)[\\w ]*(?:is|=) *([\\d,]+)")

for (e <- examples) {
  val m = p.matcher(e)
  if (m.matches()) {
    println(e + " matched")
    println("group 0: " + m.group(0))
    println("group 1: " + m.group(1))
    println("group 2: " + m.group(2))
  } else {
    println(e + " didn't match")
  }
}
```

Output:

```
The Yearly order limit = 5,000 matched
group 0: The Yearly order limit = 5,000
group 1: Yearly
group 2: 5,000
monthly order limit is 5 matched
group 0: monthly order limit is 5
group 1: monthly
group 2: 5
```